# Apache2 virtual hosts order (00- before 000-)

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I need to load three virtual hosts in an exact order to make my configuration scheme work as expected.

1. `default` (Apache default virtualhost)
2. `phpmyadmin` (a virtualhost that serves phpMyAdmin to all pma.* subdomains)
3. `mysite.com` (my website's virtualhost)

When Apache loads the `default` virtualhost from `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, it becomes `000-default` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` so it is the first (default) virtual host that Apache tries when a request is received.

Thus, I renamed my virtualhost from `phpmyadmin` to `00-phpmyadmin` so Apache would try, in order:

```
000-default
00-phpmyadmin
mysite.com
```

To my surprise, `00-phpmyadmin` comes **BEFORE** `000-default`!
See the output of `apache2ctl -S`:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server MY_SERVER_HOSTNAME (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/00-phpmyadmin:1)
     port 80 namevhost MY_SERVER_HOSTNAME (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/00-phpmyadmin:1)
     port 80 namevhost MY_SERVER_HOSTNAME (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com:1)
Syntax OK
```

I had to rename `00-phpmyadmin` to `0phpmyadmin` to make it work as expected:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server MY_SERVER_HOSTNAME (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost MY_SERVER_HOSTNAME (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost MY_SERVER_HOSTNAME (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/0phpmyadmin:1)
     port 80 namevhost mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com:1)
Syntax OK
```

Do you know why Apache behaves this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII code for the hyphen character is 0x2d. ASCII code for the digit zero is 0x30. Hyphen comes first.

If you ever see a file listing which appears to be sorted but has `000-` before `00-` your locale is probably "helping" you by skipping punctuation in its string comparison routine.

Comment: Of course... I should have thought of this! Thank you.